# Not able to get all repositories through github API

Tags: go, github-api

I want to allow the users to signup using github account, and display all his/her private and public repositories. I am able to get the token from github and get the repositories (both public and private), but the only problem is that it is not returning all repositories (i.e. some repositories are not fetched).

I am using golang for server side implementation.
Using [this](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/google/go-github/-/info/GoPackage/github.com/google/go-github/github/-/RepositoriesService/List) method to get repositories.

Comment: The comment for the method youre linking to (List user repositories) says: "List **public** repositories for the specified user" (my emphasis). So the "some repositories are not fetched" is probably because those arent public.

Comment: Hi I've updated the link, I am using "(*RepositoriesService).List(user string, opt *RepositoryListOptions) ([]Repository, *Response, error) " method to get the repos.

Comment: and also please note that I'm able to get private repos, the only problem is it is not returning complete list.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `PerPage` attribute of the `ListOptions` value?

Comment: @robbrit thanks a lot man it worked...thanx again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all the commands that accept a `ListOptions` argument have a `PerPage` attribute. In order to get all the data, you'll have to iterate through the pages using the `Page` attribute until the number of results you get is less than `PerPage`.

In Go-ish pseudo-code, it'd look like this:

```
totalResults := []Result{}
for page := 0; ; page++ {
  results := fetch current page
  totalResults = append(totalResults, results)
  if len(results) < per page {
    break
  }
}
```

You can see the `ListOptions` struct defined [here](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/5c1b3a05b41ae630de925007cd8f3e52909d1dbb/github/github.go#L130).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by robbrit to get all repos we have to use PerPage option, because by default only 30 repos are returned. That solved my problem.